# Grep doesn't match carriage return characters

Tags: grep, cygwin, newlines

I'm trying to [find lines with the carriage return character](https://superuser.com/q/194668/16275), but I'm not getting the results I'd expect.  I've whittled it down to this proof-of-concept:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Aodh 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) 2015-06-09 12:22 x86_64 Cygwin

$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.21
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

$ od -c cr_poc.txt
0000000   h   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   l   d   ;  \r  \n  \r  \n
0000020

$ od -x cr_poc.txt
0000000 6568 6c6c 206f 6f77 6c72 3b64 0a0d 0a0d
0000020

$ grep $'\r' cr_poc.txt; echo $?
1
```

I've tried various other ways of grepping for the `\r` character, but none have worked.

Notice this is on Cygwin, which certainly could be part of the problem.

Comment: I think Cygwin can be (and in your case, probably is) configured to use CR-LF line endings, so that `\r\n` is is seen as the line ending, meaning `grep`'s patterns never reach it.

Comment: @muru good theory, though unless I'm misreading [this page](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html) Cygwin switches between text and binary modes depending on usage (and in my case I'm running the POC from `/tmp`, which sounds like it should be treated as binary).  I don't see a way to configure Cygwin to default to binary instead of text.

Comment: Hmmm. Try with `-U`. My cygwin grep (a bit old, 2.14) says about `-U` : "Treat  the  file(s) as binary.  By default, under MS-DOS and MS-Windows, grep guesses the file type by looking at  the  contents of  the first 32KB read from the file.  If grep decides the file is a text file, it strips the CR characters  from  the  original file  contents  (to  make  regular expressions with ^ and $ work correctly).  Specifying -U overrules this guesswork, causing all files  to be read and passed to the matching mechanism verbatim; ..."

Comment: Well whadda know, I'd tried `-u` but hadn't seen `-U`.  If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @dimo414, whether a file is treated as text or binary isn't related to the directory it's in, but how it is opened.  The `fopen()` C library function takes a flag that says whether to open the file in text or binary mode.

Comment: @godlygeek according to the link I posted above, text vs. binary behavior *is* affected by the path to the file, "*If the filename is specified as a POSIX path ... the default is specified by the mount flag....  If the file is specified via a MS-DOS pathname ... the default is binary.*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Poking around with various inputs, I felt `grep` did its own magic for line-endings:

```
$ printf "foo\rbar\n" | grep -oz $'\r' | od -c
0000000  \r  \n
0000002
$ printf "foo\rbar\r\n" | grep -oz $'\r' | od -c
0000000
$ printf "foo\rbar\r" | grep -oz $'\r' | od -c
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n
0000004
```

(The `-z` was my lame attempt to make `grep` match everything.) And so I searched the manpage for `LF`, leading me to:

```
-U, --binary
      Treat the file(s) as binary.  By default, under MS-DOS  and  MS-
      Windows,  grep  guesses the file type by looking at the contents
      of the first 32KB read from the file.  If grep decides the  file
      is  a  text  file, it strips the CR characters from the original
      file contents (to make regular expressions with  ^  and  $  work
      correctly).  Specifying -U overrules this guesswork, causing all
      files to be read and passed to the matching mechanism  verbatim;
      if  the  file is a text file with CR/LF pairs at the end of each
      line, this will cause some regular expressions  to  fail.   This
      option  has  no  effect  on  platforms other than MS-DOS and MS-
      Windows.
```